# How to get and display the results from db in dynamic dropdowns of html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Hi I am new to php and ajax and I am trying to show the results of db in my dropdown
actually here I am having a dropdown and when I click on add button It will add another dropdown here my problem I am able to show the results in the first dropdown from db but when I click on add button the results are not displaying in the dynamically adding dropdown

The code that I wrote is

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-body">
<h3>Share with people</h3>
<p style="color: red; display: none;" id="errUsr">
Please select atleast one email, to share.
</p>
<div id="email-list-container" class=""></div>
<i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true style="float: right; margin-right: 50px;" onclick="addEmail();"></i>
<div class="container">
<div class="form-group shrBtns">
<input type="hidden" id="hdn_tmId" value="0" />
</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
\$(document).ready(function () {
      addEmail();

      })
    function addEmail() {
    \$('#errUsr').hide();
    
        \$.ajax({
            url :'propage.php',
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
            data : '&userId='+\$('#hdn_userid').val()+'&action=getEmails',
            success : function(res){
                res.users.forEach(function(email) {
                \$('#share_by_email').append('<option>' + email + '</option>');
            });
          },
        });           
    \$('#email-list-container').append(
          `<div class='form-group' style='display:flex'>
                  <select class='form-control' name='email' id='share_by_email' id='Email-${emailListIndex}''>
                <option value='' disabled selected>Select your email</option>
              </select>
                 </div>`
        );
        }
```

Here when I open the modal and the results from db are showing in the dropdown if I click the add fa-fa-icon I am getting another dropdown but the results from db are not showing can anyone help me

Comment: Remove `\` before `$` and `$('#email-list-container').append` define before your ajax method. I couldn't see where this data came from. `emailListIndex`